# Is there a way to return the same data for every ASP.Net MVC action in a particular controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller with several actions that all return a set of data that's the same among them all. Instead of adding the data to the ViewBag in every single action, is there some pattern or attribute or something I can call or set to add the same data to the viewdata or viewbag for every action, or some other better way to perform the get the same data in every view without calling the method in every action?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you are looking for is an `ActionFilter`, then override `OnActionExecuting`. Here is one of my ActionFilters that appends the current logged in user to the ViewBag:

```
public class AppendUserActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    ...
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        User currentUser = _sessionManager.CurrentUser;

        dynamic viewBag = filterContext.Controller.ViewBag;
        viewBag.CurrentUser = currentUser;
    }
   ...
}
```

Then you need to apply the attribute wherever you want this to take place. If you append it to an action, that action will get the added entry in the ViewBag. If you append it to a controller, all of its actions will get it. If you append it to a base controller and have all your controllers subclass it, then all your actions in your entire app get it

```
 [AppendUserActionFilter]
 public class MyController : Controller {

      public ActionResult Foo() {
           ....
      }
 }
```

Comment: ActionFilterAttribute exists in two namespaces: System.Web.Mvc and System.Web.Http.Filters. Are there any differences? Which one should be used? I think this will help avoid confusion for newbies (like me).

Answer (score 3):

One workable solution, you can assign through Constructor of your controller

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public HomeController()
        {
            ViewData["Common"] = "Some Data";
        }
     }
```

It will be available to all Actions in the HomeController